# Get all asset names on the thingsboard widget

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

I created 5 assets like this:

[image]

How can I get the names of all assets on the Thinngsboard Widget?

Answer (score 0):

For listing your assets on dashboard there is a entities widget available in ThingsBoard 
For more reference 
https://youtu.be/5qZRSBYTDN4